# Getting a Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs on x:Bind to a textbox

Tags: c#, uwp, template10

I'm working on a simple UWP app. I want to make it possible for the user to enter some monetary value, in this case an hourly rate. The data type is decimal. Here's the property from the viewmodel:

```
private decimal hourly;
public decimal Hourly
{
get => salaryConvUS.Hourly;
set
    {
       Set(ref hourly, value); //Template10 method
       salaryConvUS.Hourly = hourly;
    }
}
```

And here's the XAML code:

```
<TextBox x:Name="HourlyTextBox" 
     Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Hourly, Mode=TwoWay}"
     Style="{StaticResource CommonTextboxStyle}" />
```

It would seem to me to be pretty straight forward, but I'm getting an error that says,

> App.InitializeComponent.AnonymousMethod__3_0(object sender,
>   Windows.UI.Xaml.UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)"

in the App.g.i.cs file. I've searched for this error, but what I found didn't apply to this situation.

The one thing that might have something to do with it is a problem I know that Windows 8 applications had, in that you couldn't bind something like a textbox to a decimal data type. You had to do some sort of conversion. Is that what's going on here in UWP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TextBlock holds a string value. So you can't bind decimal value with a TextBlock directly.

Use the `ToString()` method to bind correctly.

You can use something like this -

```
private string hourly;
public string Hourly
{
    //Your Algorithm
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Mahmudal. Although I do think the issue is with the decimal data type. UWP binding doesn't seem to like it. I did try changing the Hourly to float - that worked. But your solution would also work.

Comment: In my machine, the tooltip says that I cannot assign a decimal value to a string container. So I thought that it could be a casting problem.
Anyways, glad to know that it works!